# UL 508A - Listed assembly in unlisted enclosure?

Tags: power, control, standard

I need a UL Listed industrial control panel (cf. [UL 508A](http://ulstandardsinfonet.ul.com/scopes/0508a.html)) with non-standard dimensions. I understand that "508A" shops can fabricate Listed enclosures in custom sizes, but that takes extra time and expense.

Can an industrial control panel be UL Listed if the enclosure itself is not UL Listed or Recognized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are commingling the concept of compliance with the UL/ETL 508A standard with Listing (which is a service).  There are [other](http://www.intertek.com/marks/etl-verified/) organizations that also perform compliance testing to the UL/ETL 508A standard, although UL is among the best known.

It is not possible to obtain certification to 508A unless all components are Listed or Recognized or a certification/verification is obtained at the assembly level.  You can have your industrial control panel and custom enclosure verified and stickered in compliance with UL-508A as an assembly, provided that your custom enclosure meets the requirements of the standard.

I have done this in the past to achieve Listing when a non-Listed/Recognized component or enclosure was required, although it is not a fast process.